# svn: Repository moved permanently please relocate

Tags: svn

I was trying to do a svn unlock by giving the below command

`svn unlock http://test.server.com/svn/test/server/linux/issue/conf/config.java`

```
svn: Repository moved permanently to 'http://test.server.com/svn/test/server/linux/issue/conf; please relocate
```

I think I did a mess. I am not able to access now.

Answer (score 0):

`svn checkout` a clean working copy using the correct URL and try again. If you get the same error, ask your server administrator what's going on there because it's not really a client-side issues, as far as I see.

Answer (score 0):

Just do as the response says since the repository seems to have been moved elsewhere. First relocate your repository to the new URL:

```
cd <YOUR_WORKING_COPY_ROOT>
svn relocate http://test.server.com/svn/test/server/linux/issue/conf
```